# Variable Amount of Input on the Same Line in C

Tags: c, arrays, computer-science

I have to scan the same line to get a variable amount of input (the user selects how many inputs they want to play with) for an array. I have to do it a character, an integer, and a floating-point.

I have tried for loop and did different things with spaces with nested loops and statements inside of the foor loop but nothing is working. 
*edit* this isn't all of my code I added more of it so people have a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int ranNum1, ranNum2, ranNum3, ranNum4, playNum, ranPlay;
    int index1, index2, index3;

    printf("How many choices do you want to play with? ");
    scanf("%d", &playNum);
    srand(time(0));
    ranPlay = playNum + 1;
    ranNum1 = rand() % ranPlay;
    ranNum2 = rand() % ranPlay;
    ranNum3 = rand() % ranPlay;
    ranNum4 = rand() % 5;
    int kids[playNum];
    char marry [playNum];
    float money [playNum];
    printf("Who do you want to marry?\n");
    printf("(enter %d first name initials) ", playNum);
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < playNum; index1 + 1) {
        scanf("%c", &marry[index1]);
    }
    printf("How many kids do you want?\n");
    printf("(enter %d whole numbers) ", playNum);
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < playNum; index2 + 1) {
        scanf("%d", &kids[index2]);
    }
    printf("How much money do you want?\n");
    printf("(enter %d decimal amounts) ", playNum);
    for (index3 = 0; index3 < playNum; index3 + 1) {
        scanf("%f", &money[index3]);
    }
}
```

It compiles, it's just that when I run it it doesn't run right, when I input 3 characters and click enter, rather than printing the "How many kids do you want?" it just is blank.

Comment: well for starters, `index1 + 1` doesn't update `index`. You need to change that to `index = index + 1` or `index++`. But please edit your question and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What's `playNum`, `marry`, `kids`, and `money`?

Comment: `scanf` foible #7: `%c` is different.  You might just need to use `" %c"` (note the leading space).

Comment: "It compiles" but not without warnings. MSVC says *'+': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect*. It's still in the first loop, not having advanced the control varaible.

Comment: making the for loop have index1++ helped and so did " %c" with a space, thank you guys so much, this is my first post here and the help was amazing. You guys did in 20 minutes what I couldnt do for the past 3 days.

Comment: How to write a loop: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &playNum);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values)  (from any of the `scanf()` family of functions) to assure the operation was successful.  in this case, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <time.h>` to expose the prototype for the `time()` function

Comment: the `time()` function returns a `time_t` which is signed.  but `srand()` is expecting a `unsigned` value.  Suggest: `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );`

Answer (score 0):

running the latest posted code through the `gcc` compiler results in:

```
gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled.c"  
untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:10:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘time’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     srand(time(0));
           ^~~~
untitled.c:10:11: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
untitled.c:21:47: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     for (index1 = 0; index1 < playNum; index1 + 1) {
                                        ~~~~~~~^~~
untitled.c:26:47: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     for (index2 = 0; index2 < playNum; index2 + 1) {
                                        ~~~~~~~^~~
untitled.c:31:47: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     for (index3 = 0; index3 < playNum; index3 + 1) {
                                        ~~~~~~~^~~
untitled.c:5:36: warning: variable ‘ranNum4’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int ranNum1, ranNum2, ranNum3, ranNum4, playNum, ranPlay;
                                    ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:5:27: warning: variable ‘ranNum3’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int ranNum1, ranNum2, ranNum3, ranNum4, playNum, ranPlay;
                           ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:5:18: warning: variable ‘ranNum2’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int ranNum1, ranNum2, ranNum3, ranNum4, playNum, ranPlay;
                  ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:5:9: warning: variable ‘ranNum1’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int ranNum1, ranNum2, ranNum3, ranNum4, playNum, ranPlay;
         ^~~~~~~
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Don't let that final message from the compiler: "Compilation finished successfully."  fool you.  That is just the compiler saying that it implemented some kind (usually wrong) of work around for the problems in the code.